# Java & MySQL - Changes in the database (Triggers, Producer/Consumer?)

Tags: java, mysql, triggers

I'm developing a small Java logistics system where customers can place orders, and a shopkeeper can view them.

The shopkeeper can view the orders in a `JTable`, but when a customer places an order, I want the shopkeeper to be able to see the updated `JTable` immediately. As in, the shopkeeper has a live view of the Orders table so to speak.

The only way I can think of achieving this is by having a timer that checks for changes in a table, then updates the `JFrame` accordingly, but looks like it will slow down the database quite a lot.

Is there any better solutions?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a back-end, or just a DB?

It sounds more like you want something with a back-end messaging system to inform clients when models have changed. Doing it with just a DB will likely prove unsatisfactory long- and short-term.

With a reasonable back-end in place it'd be a lot easier to throw a web interface on top as well.

Comment: No, there's just the MySQL DB and the Java side to it.